# Elastic Transcoder: Duplicate output key error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Over the last day we started getting an interesting error when trying to push a transcoding job with the PHP SDK:

```
'Aws\ElasticTranscoder\Exception\ElasticTranscoderException' with message 'Error executing "CreateJob" on "https://elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/jobs"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: 400 ValidationException (client): Playlists '64k' is a duplicate of an output key. - {"message":"Playlists '64k' is a duplicate of an output key."}' in /var/www/html/app/1.0/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php:152
```

The settings we're pushing to Elastic Transcoder:

```
        'PipelineId'      => $this->config['pipeline_id'],
        'OutputKeyPrefix' => "$prefix/",
        'Input'           => [
            'Key' => "uploads/$input_filename.$input_extension",
        ],
        'Playlists'       => [
            'OutputKeys' => [$bitrate],
            'Name'       => $bitrate,
            'Format'     => 'HLSv4',
        ],
        'Outputs'         => [
            'PresetId'        => $preset_id,
            'Key'             => $bitrate,
            'SegmentDuration' => '9.0',
        ],
```

where `$bitrate` is `'64k'` with the (target) end result of the transcoding job creating the files: `64k.ts`, `64k.m3u8`, `64k_v4.m3u8`.

My first thought was possibly an S3 key conflict due to the prefix existing already but even after clearing the output bucket the error remained. And as far as I'm aware `64k.ts` and `64k.m3u8` are treated as distinct objects in S3.

Does the duplicate output key in this case refer to an S3 object or perhaps a conflict in the transcoding job?

Further info:
Changing `Playlists:Name` to anything but bitrate, `$bitrate . '_v3'`, seems to prevent the error. I can still go into the output bucket at the specified prefix and rename `64k_v3.m3u8` to `64k.m3u8` with no issues. In this case, why is Elastic Transcoder blocking creation of a playlist named `64k.m3u8`?